# Ajax post request sending null data when deployed but working locally in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send some data from my view to my controller using ajax which is working fine on localhost but when I deploy to AWS the request starts sending null data. Any suggestions as to what I can do to resolve this?

ajax request

```
var postdata = { password: password, name: name, email: email, designation: designation, comp: comp, phone: phone, country: country, state: state, cid: id };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("RegisterUser", "Home")',
    data: postdata,
    traditioal: true,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == "") {
            alert("already exists");
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = data;
        }

    }
})
```

Controller Action

```
public ActionResult RegisterUser(string password, string email, string name, string country, string state, string designation,string cid,string comp,string phone)
{
}
```

I have also tried not using traditional but it is still sending null. I tried to send using formData but it was also sending null parameters to the controller.

**UPDATE:**
I just figured out that for some reason the action is getting called twice. First when it is called the data is coming properly but the second time the data is coming null. Any idea why could it be getting called twice?

Comment: Are you sure it is hitting your ActionMethod in AWS? Are all parameters going null or only a few?

Comment: yes it is hitting the action method as functions inside the action are getting called but all the parameters are null. It is however working perfectly on localhost.

Comment: It is difficult to say what could be wrong, you can debug using the developer console in browser and check what post data is passed to the back end using the network tab.